# Convert Universal app to iPad app

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

How exactly would I convert a universal app from working on both the iPhone and iPad to just the iPad. If I submit it right now, it will appear as an universal app on the App Store, so how do I trick it into thinking this is just an iPad app, without creating a whole new project? I know that this is a weird question, but does anyone know? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to change the `-targeted-device-family` build setting.